# Multiple rails apps on Phusion Passenger on Apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, apache, passenger

I have an rails application setup on a linux server which works fine and I can access it through:

machine.mydomain.com

the passenger setup file (/etc/apache2/httpd.conf) has this section:

```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName machine.mydomain.com 
      DocumentRoot /var/www/public    
      <Directory /var/www/public>
         AllowOverride all              
         Options -MultiViews           
      </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
```

I added a new rails app under the same directory (it will not be there indefinately, it's only for testing) under the subdirectory sss and added a new section in the file:

```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName machine.mydomain.com/sss
      DocumentRoot /var/www/sss/public
      <Directory /var/www/sss/public>
         AllowOverride all
         Options -MultiViews
      </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're using rack, you have to change your httpd.conf like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName machine.mydomain.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/public
  <Directory /var/www/public>
     AllowOverride all
     Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>

  RackBaseURI /sss
  <Directory /var/www/sss/public>
    Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>    

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Now I get this error:

Passenger error #2
An error occurred while trying to access '/var/www/public/sss': Cannot resolve possible symlink '/var/www/public/sss': No such file or directory (2)

Comment: I think you-re using some *nix OS, so you have to add a symlink in your document root: `ln -s /var/www/sss/public /var/www/sss`. For any further reference you can take a look at the documentation [link](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_deploying_to_a_virtual_host_8217_s_root)